# Good code editor to develop GTK+ application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk

Can you tell me a good code editor to develop GTK+ application (highlight syntax etc) for Ubuntu Linux. I use geyne editor, but I want some features, for instance, which is in VAssistsX (in Visual Studio for C++) or ReSharper for C#. May be use NetBeans? And may be install any plugins in geyne or gedit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try Anjuta since it is the official Gnome IDE https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Anjuta

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there isn't any real substitute for any of the tools you mentioned or even Visual Studio as a whole and those who are supposed to substitute for some or part of their functionality are merely *impostors*, sort of to say, since they aren't even close.

You will most likely fall back to basic tools/ides like [Anjuta](http://www.anjuta.org/),[Geany](http://www.geany.org/), [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) or Vim in the end, after you've exhausted enough resources trying to find a substitute for Visual Studio for Linux. :-) Learning you way with standard command line developing tools will help you along the road though, even if it might seem hard.